# How to compile rust crate using `-Zpanic-in-drop=abort`?

Tags: rust, compilation, rust-crates, crate

Compile Rust crate using `-Zpanic-in-drop=abort` and `build-std` options got lots of errors as below:

```
error: the crate `std` is compiled with the panic-in-drop strategy `unwind` which is incompatible with this crate's strategy of `abort`
error: the crate `core` is compiled with the panic-in-drop strategy `unwind` which is incompatible with this crate's strategy of `abort`
error: the crate `rustc_std_workspace_core` is compiled with the panic-in-drop strategy `unwind` which is incompatible with this crate's strategy of `abort`
error: the crate `alloc` is compiled with the panic-in-drop strategy `unwind` which is incompatible with this crate's strategy of `abort`
error: the crate `libc` is compiled with the panic-in-drop strategy `unwind` which is incompatible with this crate's strategy of `abort`
error: the crate `unwind` is compiled with the panic-in-drop strategy `unwind` which is incompatible with this crate's strategy of `abort`
error: the crate `cfg_if` is compiled with the panic-in-drop strategy `unwind` which is incompatible with this crate's strategy of `abort`
```

How to change `panic-in-drop` strategy from `unwind` to `abort`?

Comment: Can't reproduce this, can you provide details on how you try to compile?

Comment: For example, using `cargo build -Zbuild-std=core,alloc,std -Zpanic-in-drop=abort`. Or, what is right way to use `-Zpanic-in-drop=abort`?